# Cumsum in Pandas Dataframe but reset to zero on a specific date every new year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumsum

I have a dataframe that is in descending order of time and indexed by `Race_ID` and `Student_ID`.

```
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Mark     
1         1/10/2023      1               5        
1         1/10/2023      2               8        
1         1/10/2023      3               7        
8         1/10/2023      4               4        
8         1/1/2023       1               9        
8         1/1/2023       2               3        
8         1/1/2023       3               5        
8         1/1/2023       4               10       
2         11/9/2022      1               2        
2         11/9/2022      2               4        
2         11/9/2022      3               9        
3         17/4/2022      5               3        
3         17/4/2022      2               4        
3         17/4/2022      3               3        
3         17/4/2022      4               7        
4         1/3/2022       1               4        
4         1/3/2022       2               9        
5         1/1/2021       1               6        
5         1/1/2021       2               1        
5         1/1/2021       3               8
```

I want to create a new column `Seasonal_Mark` which is the `cumsum` of `Mark`  by each student, with the caveat that the sum is set to zero on every 1 February. So the desired outcome looks like:

```
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Mark     Seasonal_Mark 
1         1/10/2023      1               5        5
1         1/10/2023      2               8        8
1         1/10/2023      3               7        7
8         1/10/2023      4               4        4
8         1/1/2023       1               9        15 (4+2+9)
8         1/1/2023       2               3        20 (4+9+4+3)
8         1/1/2023       3               5        17 (9+3+5)
8         1/1/2023       4               10       17 (7+10)                  
2         11/9/2022      1               2        6  (4+2)
2         11/9/2022      2               4        17 (4+9+4)
2         11/9/2022      3               9        12 (9+3)
3         17/4/2022      5               3        3
3         17/4/2022      2               4        13 (4+9)
3         17/4/2022      3               3        3
3         17/4/2022      4               7        7
4         1/3/2022       1               4        4
4         1/3/2022       2               9        9
5         1/1/2021       1               6        6
5         1/1/2021       2               1        1
5         1/1/2021       3               8        8
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, which creates an adjusted year column that corresponds to the year of the date, if the date is February or later (in the year), and to the year minus 1, if the date is earlier than February (in the year). This new column is afterwards used inside `groupby`.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

m = df['Date'].dt.month
y = df['Date'].dt.year

df.assign(
    Seasonal_Mark = (df.assign(
        adjusted_year = np.where(m >= 2, y, y - 1))
    .sort_values(by='Date')
    .groupby(['Student_ID', 'adjusted_year'])['Mark'].cumsum()))
```

Output:

```
    Race_ID       Date  Student_ID  Mark  Seasonal_Mark
0         1 2023-10-01           1     5              5
1         1 2023-10-01           2     8              8
2         1 2023-10-01           3     7              7
3         8 2023-10-01           4     4              4
4         8 2023-01-01           1     9             15
5         8 2023-01-01           2     3             20
6         8 2023-01-01           3     5             17
7         8 2023-01-01           4    10             17
8         2 2022-09-11           1     2              6
9         2 2022-09-11           2     4             17
10        2 2022-09-11           3     9             12
11        3 2022-04-17           5     3              3
12        3 2022-04-17           2     4             13
13        3 2022-04-17           3     3              3
14        3 2022-04-17           4     7              7
15        4 2022-03-01           1     4              4
16        4 2022-03-01           2     9              9
17        5 2021-01-01           1     6              6
18        5 2021-01-01           2     1              1
19        5 2021-01-01           3     8              8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom yearly [`Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html) starting on the 1st of February as a secondary grouper, for this use [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) with `A-JAN` as freq:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df['Seasonal_Mark'] = (df.sort_values(by='Date')
                         .groupby(['Student_ID', df['Date'].dt.to_period('A-JAN')])
                       ['Mark'].cumsum()
                      )
```

Output:

```
    Race_ID       Date  Student_ID  Mark  Seasonal_Mark
0         1 2023-10-01           1     5              5
1         1 2023-10-01           2     8              8
2         1 2023-10-01           3     7              7
3         8 2023-10-01           4     4              4
4         8 2023-01-01           1     9             15
5         8 2023-01-01           2     3             20
6         8 2023-01-01           3     5             17
7         8 2023-01-01           4    10             17
8         2 2022-09-11           1     2              6
9         2 2022-09-11           2     4             17
10        2 2022-09-11           3     9             12
11        3 2022-04-17           5     3              3
12        3 2022-04-17           2     4             13
13        3 2022-04-17           3     3              3
14        3 2022-04-17           4     7              7
15        4 2022-03-01           1     4              4
16        4 2022-03-01           2     9              9
17        5 2021-01-01           1     6              6
18        5 2021-01-01           2     1              1
19        5 2021-01-01           3     8              8
```